# Foreach in laravel controller but got only single data

Tags: php, laravel

My data be like

```
$game = game::all();

0: {gameID: 10802, startTime: "2019-02-19 23:40:51"}
0: {gameID: 10803, startTime: "2019-02-19 23:40:51"}
0: {gameID: 10804, startTime: "2019-02-19 23:40:51"}
0: {gameID: 10805, startTime: "2019-02-19 23:40:51"}

foreach($game as $a){
return response->json($a->gameID); 
}

out put// 10802
```

I want to use all gameID,but what is my mistake? thank you

Comment: Your return is stopping the script at the first element. Thats why you'll only get the first element. As in ka_lin's answer below you can see he suggests you to make an array before the loop, and inside the loop store all ids in that array, then return the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put it in a list then return it:

```
$game = game::all();
$idList = []; //or $idList = array(); if PHP version < 5.2
foreach($game as $a){
    $idList[]=$a->gameID;
}
return response->json($idList);
```

Or the Laravel way using the [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-pluck) method on [Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections):

```
$game = game::all(); 
$plucked = $collection->pluck('gameID'); 
return response->json($plucked->all());
```

Comment: thank you It works,but how do i check if idlist = 10802 true then do something...